# RESTful service to return images from server directory

Tags: json, backbone.js, jersey

I have a Backbone.js UI interfacing with RESTful services implemented in Jersey.

May I know how to implement a RESTful service to load images from a server directory and display them on the UI?

Comment: Can you show us what you've got so far? It's easier to help if we know  what you've done already.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a File object in your Response.

```
@GET
@Path("/{filename}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getFile(@PathParam("filename") final String fileName) {

    if (fileName == null || fileName.isEmpty())
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    File file = new File(fileDirectoryPath, fileName);
    return Response.ok(file).build();
}
```

fileDirectoryPath is a String for the path to the directory you're pulling files from.